# For each loop not working in App Script runtime powered by Chrome V8

Tags: google-apps-script, foreach, v8, google-apps-script-editor

[Sorry Guys. Already edited my question.]

For each loop resulted into an error if I enable the Chrome V8 in my Apps Script. Any way to solve this issue beside disabling it? A lot of my functions use the said syntax.

For example I have a sheet containing columns week name, start date and end date *(refer on the attached image)*. Once I read them on my codes I would like to access each items using for each loop but an error occur due to v8.

```
function weeks(){

  SS = SpreadsheetApp;
  SHEET = SS.getActiveSpreadsheet();


  var sheet = SHEET.getSheetByName("Weeks");
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = "A2:D" + row;
  var arrWeeks = sheet.getRange(range).getValues();

  for each(var week in arrWeeks){

    Logger.log("week: " + week[0])
    Logger.log("start date: " + week[1])
    Logger.log("end date: " + week[2])

  }

}
```

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v0ak.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7nBv.png)

Comment: Please post your code in the question.

Comment: Why would syntax that is explicitly labeled as incompatible work?

Comment: Thanks for finding that.. knew there was one like it

Comment: @tehhow :) Just had to search both tags : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script+v8

Comment: @TheMaster thank you. Its seems that changing the statement from **each** to **for** is the only solution to this. As much as possible we are avoiding this route since a lot of our loops in the codes use the each statement.

Comment: @krafty  it's the best way. Don't avoid it.

Answer (score 4):

Read the migration documentation: [`for each (var ___ in ____)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in)  is not supported and should never be used:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration#avoid_for_eachvariable_in_object

> When migrating your script to V8, avoid using `for each (variable in object)` statements.
>
> Instead, use `for (variable in object)`

Comment: Thanks for the link. I got here by googling "apps script runtime chrome v8 dates not working". That link explains incompatibilities between Rhino and V8 along with solutions.